# How to fill holes inside a polygon in QGIS?

Tags: qgis

I need to fill/delete the lines inside the polygon. I have tried the dissolve and delete holes tools, but did not work for me.
Any ideas and thoughts to delete the holes?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Have you try the geometry tools repair from processing menu. Seems invalid geometry ?
If it's not working try to use GRASS in the processing menu : v.clean (break, snap, rmdangle and rmsa) with a snap tolerance to 0.001. If not working, then try 0.01 or 0.1 (try to find the best threshold).

Answer (score 0):

In your case, you might want to just edit the shape and delete the interior vertices at the end of those lines.